# Conditional display of data item in Polymer

Tags: polymer

I'm displaying data pulled from a JSON file and one of the JSON attributes may or may not have a value. I'd like to display text only if the value in the JSON file exists. I've tried the following, but nothing is displayed.

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="[[session]]" as="subSession">
.... Display other values from the JSON file
 <template is="dom-if" if="{{subSession.track.presentation}}">
   <div class="session-meta layout horizontal">
     <iron-icon class="session-meta-icon" icon="class"></iron-icon>
     <span>Presentation Available</span>
   </div>
 </template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what's working for me:

display Project data only if it's projectID is accepted.

```
 <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{projects_list}}" as="project">
      <template is="dom-if" if="{{project_check(project.projectID)}}">
       ...display project values here...
      </template>
 </template>
 <script>
 project_check: function(projectID) {
        console.log('project_check:');
        console.log(projectID);
        //check if  projectID is accepted here.
        //return true or false to render or not the template.
    },
 </script>
```

Comment: Thanks, do you find the project_check script necessary? I was able to get to this to work with using only the dom-if statement.

Answer (score 0):

Having not used dom-if before I wasn't sure if I was using this correctly. The code above in the question is the correct usage of this conditional. I inadvertently used the wrong variable, which should have been [[subSession.presentation]].